# Can I use dll files in android application?

Tags: java, c#, android, dll

Is it possible to use dll files *(commonly used in web application)* in an Android application?

I have a Delphi dll library and I want to use it in my app.

Comment: Yes unless some developer at google android loves C# instead of Java

Comment: how i can use dll with xamarin C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use DLLs with a native Android application. Android applications run on the JVM on a linux kernel, but DLLs are a Microsoft creation.

If this DLL is a critical component of your application and you cannot re-implement it in Java, then you may want to consider [Xamarin](https://xamarin.com/), which allows you to write applications in C#. Be aware that if you go this route there are a number of significant tradeoffs. You should ensure you fully understand these tradeoffs before making this decision.

Comment: i can use this dll with Xamarin studio C# ?  to make an android app and i want help for example or reference for this issue .

Comment: With a number of limitations, yes. You may need to recompile it, and you won't be able to reference any Win32 libraries. [See this thread for some details](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/3633/adding-existing-c-library-project).

Comment: if i make it with web-service  to retrieve xml and request xml it will  work or not ?

Comment: Web service don't know and don't care what happens on the server. All they care about is the data that is output. So yes, that is also an option.